# Multi-protein drug treatments

Tags: genetics, dna, proteins, pharmacology, snp

Apologies if this an obvious question - I am very new to this. I am, as of now, under the impression that multiple SNP variations interact to create multiple mutated proteins, which ultimately results in a variant phenotype.

I am wondering if the standard method of treating is this is by creating a drug that has a combination of all of the non-mutated versions of the proteins, or if drug makers simply use the protein that they believe has the biggest impact?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Proteins are long strings of amino acids.  Drugs are generally not proteins; they are small molecules.